# Background scripts load order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm observing something odd. I have a few background scripts, well actually a lot - like 18

```
....
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "scripts/namespace.js",
    "scripts/frameworks/honeybadger.js",
    "scripts/frameworks/underscore.js",
    "scripts/frameworks/mixin.js",
    "scripts/frameworks/analytics.js",
    "scripts/modules/worker.js",
    "scripts/modules/i18n.js",
    "scripts/modules/url.js",
    "scripts/trackers/error_tracker.js",
    "scripts/trackers/analytics_tracker.js",
    "scripts/lib/page_context_menu.js",
    "scripts/lib/selection_context_menu.js",
    "scripts/lib/omnibox.js",
    "scripts/lib/sync_store.js",
    "scripts/lib/local_store.js",
    "scripts/lib/example_tags.js",
    "scripts/persistence/tag.js",
    "scripts/init/tag_feature.js",
    "scripts/initialize_background.js"
  ],
  "persistent": false
}, 
....
```

I have HoneyBadger error tracking and I'm seeing errors related to load order. The last script, `initialize_background.js` is meant to be the starting place. Yet I'm seeing errors like:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined (third script loaded)
- Uncaught ReferenceError: _qag is not defined (fifth script loaded)

Has this happened to anyone before? Can the scripts array be trusted to load scripts in order? Should note that I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: I have never encountered such an error before (yet again I had never 18 bg scripts). I couldn't find any assertion in the docs about the background scripts' being loaded in any particular order (e.g. for content scripts it is explicitely stated that they are loaded in order of "appearance"). On the other hand I would be very susrprised if they were loaded in a random order. Two suggestions: **1.** If you get to reproduce it, check the `_generated_background_page.html` of your extension to verify the order of the auto-generated `script`-tags.

Comment: [_comment character limit_] **2.** It might help to use an HTML page (using `page` instead of `scripts` in your manifest) to ensure the `script`-tags appear in proper order.

Comment: the order in `_generated_background_page.html` seems to be correct. I just implemented a concating build setup to join all the scripts into one `background_script.js`. I'm confident that will fix the problem, but I'm still a bit puzzled on why this was happening.

Comment: I just had this happen and it was because there was an error in one of the scripts I was loading.  I was clearing the console in the final script and that was making me miss the earlier error which lead to some variables not being set.  Check for 'console cleared' message at the top of the console logs.  They do always seem to get loaded in the order specified for me.